# Basic Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

The question is is a true or false statement.

‘’If the number of unknowns in a linear system exceeds the number of equations, then the system must be consistent’’?

I know that a linear system is consistent if it has at least one solution and inconsistent if it has no solutions.
In my opinion: The geometrical view says that the lines should either have one intersection to be consistent. Or the lines should coincide to have infinitely many solutions. In both cases the linear system will be consistent.

I could give an example and say that 2x+1y=1 is a system of linear equations where the number of unknowns exceeds the number of equations. 
From here I don’t know how to continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+y+z=0\\x+y+z=1,\end{array}\right.$$which

- has $2$ equations
- has $3$ unknowns
- is inconsistent.

Geometrically, what I am doing here is to look for a point which belongs to two planes which are parallel and distinct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For me it seems like it is 3 dimensions due to the three unknowns? And then you connect this with two, two dimension planes? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Djhoe $x+y+z=0$ is the equation of a plane in $3$-dimensional space and $x+y+z=1$ is the equation of *another* (parallel) plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: So two parallel lines in 3 dimensional space will not intersect. Therefore it has no solution, so it must be incosistent?

Comment: @Djhoe No. There are *no* lines here. What we have here are two planes, not lines.

Comment: Thank you for your answers

Comment: @Djhoe I'm glad I could help.

Comment: It has infinitely many!

Comment: @Djhoe It has infinitely many *what*?

Comment: I wanted to say today I realized it is consistent. Because the planes can intersect at one point, or intersect infinitely many times

Comment: So it must be consistent

Comment: @Djhoe Do you believe that my example is a consistent system of equations? Please provide a solution then. In other words, give an example of three numbers $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that $x+y+z$ is equal to $0$ and to $1$ simultaneously.

Comment: It has no solution

Comment: @Djhoe If it has no solution, then it is *not* consistent.

Comment: True, I was mixing up some things.. 1 week as an undergrad :) thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

A system $AX=B$ is consistent if and only if the rank of the matrix $A$  and the rank of the augmented matrix $AB$ are the same.